# Drag & Drop Javascript sortable with moving marker?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, sorting

I am searching through "drag & drop sortable" Javascript libraries such as Prototype's sortable, JQuery's sortable, and a number of standalone ones.

I feature that I can't find (but know it's out there) is, I can't think of a better word, "delayed" sorting so that when I move an item around on the list, **it will not be moved immediately, but a line or other kind of marker will appear showing where the item would end up if I dropped it right now**. This functionality can for example be found in Windows when moving items around in the start menu.

Could anybody point me towards a Javascript solution that can do this? Prototype or standalone would be preferred for the current project, but JQuery is fine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at script.aculo.us Sortables and property called *ghosting*.

**Refer:**

https://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous

http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/sortable-create/

Comment: Sortables can be definitely used for this kind of task, I have used them myself to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Ghosting and the patch mentioned here: http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/sortable-create was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I use jQuery to do this in one of my projects. 
On the list element, lets say an element , I assign the class sortable:

```
<ul class="sortable">
```

Then I've a Javascript function like this:

```
$(function() {
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "placeholder-sortable",
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var listElements = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        //Your code
    }
});
$( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

With this the new order is saved into the variable listElements, in which there are stored the ids of the different li items.